# Django, TemplateSyntaxError at. Help me

Tags: django

I am doing a website by Django, but I have a registor problem, which I don't know how to solve,help me).Before last change, everything was working, but I have changed only this files:

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import *
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse


def index(request):
    cat = ["Cars", "Plates", "Fruits", "Phones", "Bananas"]
    return render(request, "firstapp/index.html",
                  context={"cat": cat})


def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("About")


def contact(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/about")


def details(request):
    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect("/")
```

index.html

```
{% extends "firstapp/base.html" %} 
{% block title %}Index{% endblock title %}
{% block header %}Main page{% endblock header %}
{% block content%)
<p>Types of products</p>
{% for i in cat %}
          <li>{{ i }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

and I got this problem:
Invalid block tag on line 9: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

```
1   {% extends "firstapp/base.html" %} 
2   {% block title %}Index{% endblock title %}
3   {% block header %}Main page{% endblock header %}
4   {% block content%)
5   <p>Types of products</p>
6   {% for i in cat %}
7             <li>{{ i }}</li>
8        {% endfor %}
9   {% endblock content %}
```

I don't know what to do in this case, help me!

Comment: The end of line 4 is incorrect. Should end with `%}`, but ends with `%)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on line 4. There is a mistake there. You are using

```
{% block content%)
```

instead of

```
{% block content %}
```

> Note: It should be `}` instead of `)`